# Replace NAs between Values with Sequence

Tags: r, dataframe, na, missing-data

I have a data frame with NA values. I want to replace these NAs with a sequence between the values before and after the NAs.

Consider the following example:

```
# Example data
df <- data.frame(x1 = c(5, NA, NA, 10, NA),
                 x2 = c(NA, 2, NA, - 10, NA),
                 x3 = c(10, NA, 15, NA, 20))
df
# x1  x2 x3
#  5  NA 10
# NA   2 NA
# NA  NA 15
# 10 -10 NA
# NA  NA 20
```

The NAs between two values should be replaced with a sequence. NAs at the beginning or the end should remain NA:

```
# Expected output

#       x1   x2     x3
#        5   NA     10
# 6.666667    2   12.5
# 8.333333   -4     15
#       10  -10   17.5
#       NA   NA     20
```

How could I replace NAs between two values in an automatized way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The na.approx function in zoo does this interpolation very easily.

```r
df <- data.frame(x1 = c(5, NA, NA, 10, NA),
                 x2 = c(NA, 2, NA, - 10, NA),
                 x3 = c(10, NA, 15, NA, 20))
df
#>   x1  x2 x3
#> 1  5  NA 10
#> 2 NA   2 NA
#> 3 NA  NA 15
#> 4 10 -10 NA
#> 5 NA  NA 20

zoo::na.approx(df)
#>             x1  x2   x3
#> [1,]  5.000000  NA 10.0
#> [2,]  6.666667   2 12.5
#> [3,]  8.333333  -4 15.0
#> [4,] 10.000000 -10 17.5
#> [5,]        NA  NA 20.0
```

Created on 2019-02-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with *imputeTS* package:

```
# Example data
df <- data.frame(x1 = c(5, NA, NA, 10, NA),
             x2 = c(NA, 2, NA, - 10, NA),
             x3 = c(10, NA, 15, NA, 20))

library("imputeTS")
na.interpolation(df, option = "linear)
```

For imputeTS::na.interpolation you can choose a different interpolation method via the parameter option (option = "spline" or option = "stine").

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution!